# php reCaptcha will not return confirmation after submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form with the reCaptcha on my website  www.boakustikk.no
Almost everything is working. The email is delivered, only if reCaptcha is performed correctly, as it should be. But the return confirmation is only a blank, empty page, in both cases. It seems that the function in line 31 to 41, in the form.php, is not working. Here is my form.php and the form.html :

form.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'secret';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success):
            //contact form submission code
            $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
            $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
            $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';

            $to = 'kontakt@boakustikk.no';
            $subject = 'New contact form have been submitted';
            $htmlContent = "
                <h1>Henvendelse fra din hjemmeside</h1>
                <p><b>Navn: </b>".$name."</p>
                <p><b>E-post: </b>".$email."</p>
                <p><b>Melding: </b>".$message."</p>
            ";
            // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            // More headers
            $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
            //send email
            @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        else:
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = '';
    $succMsg = '';
endif;
?>
```

form.html:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Ditt navn"  size="43" /><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Din E-post" size="43" /><br><br>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="8" cols="41"></textarea><br><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SJEKK reCAPTCHA OG SEND MELDING">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add text to `$succMsg` or `$errMsg` as appropriate, but you never echo them to the page. Nor do you output any other content as far as I can see. So the end result of executing form.php will be a blank page returned to the browser.

You need to output the messages, the simplest implementation would be:

```
echo $succMsg;
```

or

```
echo $errMsg;
```

in the error case.

But of course you might want to add some HTML markup and CSS to format it nicely, depending on your requirements.

Comment: I feel embarrassed to ask for more, but do you have an easy way to place the returns under the contact form instead of on a new blank page?

Comment: firstly, glad it's working - if the answer has helped please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote - thanks :-). Secondly, putting the returns under the contact form is tricky because they are on two different pages currently. If you merge form.html and form.php then it would be quite straightforward - you can just put the `echo` statement in any place you like on the page, and you could have an `if` statement to only show it if contains any text (so, for instance, it wouldn't show if the user had not submitted the form yet).

Comment: Sorry to come back to this issue, but I have not been able to get the returns under or over the contact form. The returns still shows up on a blank page. I have tried to merge the form.html and the form.php in one file stored in the file manager, but then nothing works?? May be I am stupid, I accept that, but if anyone will tell me how I will be very happy! I do not know how a if statement looks like and not where the echo statement should be placed.

Comment: you'll have to define "nothing works" a bit more clearly - I don't know exactly what you've changed. An if statement looks like it does in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php. But if you are still stuck after that please ask a new question with your latest code and and link to it from here, I will happily take a look

Comment: I have opened a new question about this issue.

Comment: The new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797549/how-to-get-recaptcha-returns-under-or-over-the-contact-form